# Safemoon: why the condition from != uniswapV2Pair before swapAndLiquify

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I'm playing with Safemoon (https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol/blob/main/Safemoon.sol)

I cannot explain why the **from != uniswapV2Pair** condition before **swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance)**.

In this way, all the buy transaction (so from the pair to the buyer) are not affected by the liquidity fee. I think it is wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

- `from`: is a input parameter of a method `_transfer`.
- `uniswapV2Pair`: is a variable initialized in SafeMoon's constructor at line 760 in this way:

  ```
   // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
  uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
  .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
  ```

In the code above when the contract has deployed, it is created an address for exchange between the first Token and second Token.
The condition **from != uniswapV2Pair** is saying that the address passed into 'from' variable must be not the address in which exchange the two token.
In other words, the uniswapV2Pair address cannot perform swap and liquify operations.